# Java multiplying doubles and casting to an integer

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

I am using Java 7

I am trying to multiply two doubles and convert them to an integer as seen here:

```
double xp = value*multiplier; // These are both doubles
int exp = (int) xp; // I suspect the problem is here
System.out.println("output: "+exp);
```

Currently value is 14 and the multiplier is 50, however the system prints out 21. Is Java thinking 14 * 50 is 21 or is the double to int conversion causing this.

I have tried multiplying them together like this:

```
int xp = (int) (value*multiplier);
```

However this produces the same output of 21.

I have previously tried to cast a double to an int and it worked flawlessly. I have tried that method onto here which is what I showed you first and it works in the other place, but not here.

Once again: value = 14 and multiplier = 50

Why is this output being produces and how can I fix it to produce the correct math output.

NOTE: You may notice neither of these numbers have decimals making it a double. These numbers can be decimals depending on the users input.

More code:

```
double multiplier = 1.0;
if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().hasItemMeta())
{
    if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().hasLore())
    {
        if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("§7BlockExperience I"))
        {
            multiplier = main.getConfig().getDouble("expenchlevel1");
        }
        if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("§7BlockExperience II"))
        {
            multiplier = main.getConfig().getDouble("expenchlevel2");
        }
        if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("§7BlockExperience III"))
        {
            multiplier = main.getConfig().getDouble("expenchlevel3");
        }
        if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("§7BlockExperience IV"))
        {
            multiplier = main.getConfig().getDouble("expenchlevel4");
        }
        if(p.getInventory().getItemInHand().getItemMeta().getLore().contains("§7BlockExperience V"))
        {
            multiplier = main.getConfig().getDouble("expenchlevel5");
        }
    }
}
```

and for the variable value

```
int value = main.getConfig().getInt("blockexperience."+key);
```

This path is working with no errors and I put 50 there

When printing out both values are what I expected value: 14 multiplier:50.0

Comment: please add the code where you assign the values to `value` and `multiplier`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get 700. Clearly your input values are not what you think they are. Don't jump to conclusions about Java when the fault is millions of times more likely to be in your code or your assumptions. Edit reveals truly terrible code. Not even an `else`, and you should be using a `Map`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this result. For me, the result is `700` (as expected). Running on Java 1.8.0_45. Did you recompile the code?

Comment: Print `value` and `modifier`. One of those (at least) doesn't contains what you expect. (Code looks OK)

Comment: How do you know the values? Print out `System.out.println("value: "+value);` and `System.out.println("multiplier: "+multiplier);`

Comment: Debugging is useful. Try to inspect multiplier and value.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are either mistaken about the values of `value` and `multiplier`, or there is a problem with your methodology; e.g. how you are compiling and running the code.

> Is Java thinking 14 * 50 is 21 or is the double to int conversion causing this.

IMO, neither.

Basically, your initial code works for me (Java 8) .... and here is the evidence, cut-and-pasted from my LXTerminal session.

```
[steve@newbox tmp]$ javac Exp.java 
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java Exp 
output: 700
[steve@newbox tmp]$ cat Exp.java 
public class Exp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double value = 14;
        double multiplier = 50;
        double xp = value*multiplier; // These are both doubles
        int exp = (int) xp; // I suspect the problem is here
        System.out.println("output: "+exp);
    }
}
[steve@newbox tmp]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
[steve@newbox tmp]$
```

---

**UPDATE** -- Looking at the additional code fragments you have posted (so far), I still do not see a convincing "chain of evidence" to show that `value` and `multiplier` have the values that you believe that they have.

Answer (score 0):

**Example code:**

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {   

        double value = 14.0;
        double multiplier = 50.0;

        // 1) Set breakpoint here
        double xp = value * multiplier;
        int exp = (int) xp;
        System.out.println("Output (Double): " + exp);      

        // 2) Or set breakpoint here
        int expInt = (int) (value * multiplier);
        System.out.println("Output (Int): " + expInt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Output (Double): 700
Output (Int): 700
```

I am getting 700 for both (using Java 7 as well).
The issue with your code lies somewhere else, you need to show us all the relevant code to get a better answer.

Another option: You could set breakpoint at the line of code doing the multiplication, e.g.

```
double xp = value * multiplier;
```

and use the debugger to check what the values (i.e. value & multiplier) are at the time of multiplication.
From there, you could narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: @weston At least, this proves to the OP that his/her suspicions (regarding double to int conversion, and what not) are unfounded. I don't see why this should be downvoted, since it does highlight that the problem lies somewhere else within his code.